# VBA defined function not accepting more than one variable

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA Function is not accepting two variables for a basic function.
It keeps giving a #VALUE! error.

```
Function myFunction(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    result = x + y
    myFunction = result
End Function
```

However, it works fine if I simply remove the y variable.
For example, this works perfectly:

```
Function myFunction(x As Integer) As Integer

    result = x + x
    myFunction = result

End Function
```

I am using Windows 10 Pro on a Lenovo Yoga.

Comment: If you're using your function like this in VBA - `myFunction(1,2)` try putting `call` in front of it so it would be `Call myFunction(1,2)` - or you can remove the brackets so it'd be `myFunction 1,3`

Comment: Your function should work as written (works here).  What, exactly, is the value of `y` that you are feeding in.  If it looks like a number, are there any other (non-printing) characters in the cell that would cause VBA to interpret it as text? (check by doing `len(y)`)

Comment: I have not defined y besides in the equation and even forgetting about y, I get the #VALUE! error even if I called my function as =myFunction(1,2) in order to make it sum the variable to get 3. The issue arises only when I add that second variable

Comment: OK. Is it possibly the case that your separator is the semicolon?  If so, you would need to (on the worksheet), enter the formula as `=myFunction(1;2)`  *By the way, to alert a commenter that you have posted a response to them, use `@commenters_name` in your comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using invoking your function with an Excel range with a formula such as `=myFunction(A1:A2)` an array will be sent as the first parameter and the second parameter will be missing and cause an error with the ultimate result you are getting.

Note: `=myFunction(A1, A2)` should work.

If you indeed are using a range, define myFunction as follows:

```
Function myFunction (x())
```

Comment: I am defining my function as =myFunction(A1,A2) and still getting #VALUE! It even does not work if I use =myFunction(1,2)

Comment: @Dilan I do not have a Windows PC right now. Put a breakpoint on the line contains x + y. Check out the type of each parameter.